# SSL is required PHP api Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, twitter

I'm building a Twitter application using Codeigniter however when I run the test function it directs to URL: 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' and the screen has just 'ssl is required'. I am running this on localhost.

Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: To be clear, "has anyone else had this problem" is not a great question.  Your purpose for being here is to get a solution to your problem, not to find out if anyone else has experienced it.

Comment: I apologise for my poor choice of words. I will remove the question seeming as I upset so many.

Comment: Nobody's upset.  But imagine talking to your coworker who takes things very literally.  His answer to "has anyone else had this problem" is either going to be "Yes" or "No," and you'll still not have what you need.

Comment: Don't retract your question.  That's not how things work here.  Here, have an upvote instead.

Comment: Well thankfully my coworkers would be smart enough and say "Yes, I have seen this before. Here's how to fix it...". As a mod, could you please remove my question?

Comment: Please retract my question and remove the upvote. Thanks

Comment: @Niall - *"I will remove the question seeming as I upset so many"* - for what its worth, you did not upset me. I have a defiant streak myself.

Comment: @jww I'm sorry my choice of words offended you.

Comment: @Niall - don't worry about it. You did not offend me. Believe it or not, I've been called that before (a few times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably make the calls via HTTPS, which is what the error is telling you.
Authentication is supposed to be secure, that's why the app is enforcing SSL.

Comment: now that I am testing my twitter app in localhost. Is there a way i can surpass this error?